# How to set the bars' width on a Seaborn horizontal barplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, seaborn

Trying to set the width of the bars on a horizontal bar plot with `Seaborn` but am getting the following error:

`TypeError: barh() got multiple values for argument 'width'`

This is the code:

```python
top_10_pop = df.sort_values(by="Residents").tail(10)
sns.barplot(data=top_10_pop, x="Residents", y="Commune", width=1)
plt.show()
```

Other answers state that this is an issue with the position of the parameters, but I tried to change it, use `height` instead because this is an horizontal plot, nothing works. Without the `width` parameter, I see the chart with no issues.

How to set the width of the bars in this case?

**EDIT**
I am use version `0.11.2` and trying the exact example on Seaborn website fails with same error. Maybe some compatibility issue with this version and/or my matplotlib version...

Comment: This functionality isn't supported yet in seaborn 0.11.2.  You'd need seaborn 0.12. I think there don't exist simple workarounds (apart from upgrading).